# Turning rows into table with multiple values for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

My table consists of columns statename,date,sensorvalue with thousands of entries.

```
5/10/2020  AK  12.4
6/10/2020  AK  11.7
7/10/2020  AK   9.7
8/10/2020  AK  10.0
5/10/2020  AL  5.4
6/10/2020  AL  9.6
7/10/2020  AL  8.3
8/10/2020  AL  11.1
```

I want to produce a table that looks like this:

```
     5-Oct 6-Oct 7-Oct 8-Oct etc
AK    12.4  11.7   9.7  10.0
AL     5.4   9.6   8.3  11.1
OH    12.1  13.7   9.7  13.8
```

It's like a pivot but, grouped. How do I achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Ed.

Comment: This is something you would usually do in your application layer, not in SQL. In SQL you must know the dates you want to show in the columns beforehand. In that case you can use conditional aggregation to get this result.

Comment: *It's like a pivot but, grouped.* Without like - clear pivot. Use stored procedure with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Have you thought on having your sensors on columns instead of dates?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be able to convert it like below:

```
SELECT
  StateName,
  SUM((Date = '5/10/2020') * SensorValue) AS `5-Oct`,
  SUM((Date = '6/10/2020') * SensorValue) AS `6-Oct`,
  SUM((Date = '7/10/2020') * SensorValue) AS `7-Oct`,
  SUM((Date = '8/10/2020') * SensorValue) AS `8-Oct`
  -- etc.
FROM table
GROUP BY StateName
;
```

However, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591490/turning-rows-into-table-with-multiple-values-for-each-row#comment114209729_64591490), having your data converted like that should ideally be done above sql layer.

Comment: You should not rely on the inplicit date conversion guessing your date string format correctly. Use date literals instead, e.g. `DATE '2020-10-05'`.

Answer (score 0):

As your data stand, you might need to rethink the output table as the pivot would need to have all the dates from your dataset.

You could pivot based on your sensors that are a small number like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=badb80e491c7fcc681c7b88dd25f7231).

```
SELECT ur_date, [AK], [AL]
FROM your_table
PIVOT (
MAX(sensorvalue) FOR [statename] IN ([AK],[AL]))A
```